# Will craftsman trim saw make straight cuts in 2x4?

Tags: wood, woodworking, cutting, circular-saw

I recently found a [Craftsman Circular Cordless Saw 900.112650](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/mN0AAOSwvzRXyzWo/s-l400.jpg) in a closet that I bought many years ago and never used.

Will this cordless saw make straight cuts in 2x4" treated wood?

I still have to buy the batteries (I cant find them), but I don't want to spend money on the batteries unless I know it will make clean, straight cuts on 2x4 wood.

Comment: A saw will only cut straight  if the person using it knows how to cut straight. You bought a closet many years ago and never used it ?

Comment: Yes, I bought a closet many years ago and never used it. I also found the saw.

Comment: From the picture, it looks like a mini saw.  Can the blade be extended far enough to cut the full depth of a 2x4?  If not, you will need to cut from both sides.  Also, cutting at the full depth of the blade will be a lot of load, which will quickly go through a battery charge.

Comment: This is a 3-3/8 in saw, so too small for 2x lumber. I have a similar one (very old saw with very old battery) and it can hardly cut 1x lumber.

Comment: From the looks of it, that's a 3" blade. If so, you'll not get through a 2x4. Plus, it's apt to be pretty underpowered, so not a great choice for cutting lumber.

Comment: It is junk  I doubt you could find batteries for it anyway.  Toss it  and spend your dollars on a corded circular saw. 15 years later it will still cut a 2x4

Comment: If the circular saw is “many years” old, it may use batteries (like Ni-Cd) that are not performance-competitive with newer NiMH or Li-Ion batteries.   Even a top-quality battery powered tool from, say, 2001 uses batteries which are expensive to replace but nowhere near as powerful as today’s new product.  You may not want to buy new batteries at all.  I usually buy corded tools for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely the saw will cut through in a single pass. This will require flipping the board over to cut the 10% that wasn't cut the first time. The straightest cut will require the use of a saw guide. A simple quick square would be sufficient. Doing a second cut will reduce accuracy as the guide will have to be repositioned. If you are making a cut on a single board the saw you have may work. If you are cutting a lot of 2x4s the saw will quickly use up the batteries. You will need two sets to be productive. Even with two sets you will likely use up the available batteries faster than they will recharge.